# do\while statements will not compile correctly (beginner)

Tags: c++

Please go easy on me, as I am completely new to C++ and am currently in a programming intro class :)

I'm currently having issues getting a do\while statement to compile correctly. My goal is to enter the following until the sentinel value of -1 is entered, which would wrap up the process and give me cumulative totals of my values.

Here are the values I'm needing to input for each entity:

```
 gallons used 
 starting mileage
 ending mileage
 miles driven
 miles per gallon
```

once the sentinel value is entered, it should then calculate the following for all entities combined:

```
total gallons used
total miles driven
overall average miles per gallon
```

Below is what I have so far, but it is not ending when -1 is entered. I haven't added the final values as of yet to use when -1 is entered, as I am unsure of how to proceed and am trying to just get part 1 to work properly first. Below is my code (please excuse the comments):

```
int main(void) 
{

    StartUp();   //indicates beginning of code

    double startmileage{ 0 };              //indicates starting mileage, initialized at the value of 0
    double endmileage{ 0 };                //indicates ending mileage, initialized at the value of 0
    double milesdriven{ 0 };               //indicates total miles driven, initialized at the value of 0
    double gallonsused{ 0 };               //indicates total gallons used, initialized at the value of 0
    long double milespergallon{ 0 };       //indicates total miles per gallon, initialized at the value of 0

    do
    {
        cout << "enter the gallons used:  ";                                //prompts user to enter total number of gallons used for trip
        cin >> gallonsused;                                                 //user enters data

        cout << "enter starting mileage:  ";                                //prompts user to enter start mileage for trip
        cin >> startmileage;                                                //user enters data

        cout << "enter ending mileage:  ";                                  //prompts user to enter end mileage for trip
        cin >> endmileage;                                                  //user enters data

        milesdriven = startmileage + endmileage;                            //calculates total miles driven

        cout << "Miles Driven:  " << milesdriven << endl;                   //outputs total miles driven to screen

        milespergallon = milesdriven / gallonsused;                         //calculates total miles per gallon

        cout << "Miles Per Gallon:  " << milespergallon << endl;            //outputs miles per gallon to screen
    } 

    while (gallonsused != -1);
WrapUp();  //indicates end of code

    return Success;

}
```

Here is what is occurring:

```
enter the gallons used:  12.8
enter starting mileage:  0
enter ending mileage:  277
Miles Driven:  277
Miles Per Gallon:  21.6406
enter the gallons used:  -1
enter starting mileage:
```

as you can see, it loops, but does not stop when the sentinel value is entered

Any assistance would be very much appreciated!

Thank You!

Comment: Debuggers are your friends use them.  You could easily single step through your code with a debugger to determine how the `do-while` statement is working.  No need to post here.

Comment: Try printing the value of that `double` variable after user input.

Comment: @Clarky7782 What's the ***very next line*** of code after `cin >> gallonsused;`? You're misunderstanding how a loop works. (BTW You should also double-check your understanding of the difference between compiling and running a program.)

Answer (score 3):

You're not testing `gallonsused != -1` until the end of the loop, after the user has responded to all the other prompts and it calculates the mileage.

Instead of using `do-while()`, test `gallonsused` immediately after the user enters it, and break out of the loop.

You also need variables for the total miles driven and total gallons used. After each input, you add the values for that trip to the totals, and use them in the grand totals at the end.

```
double totalmiles = 0;
double totalgallons = 0;

while (true)
    {
        cout << "enter the gallons used:  ";                                //prompts user to enter total number of gallons used for trip
        cin >> gallonsused;                                                 //user enters data
        if (gallonsused == -1) { // Check for sentinel
            break;
        }

        totalgallons += gallonsused;

        cout << "enter starting mileage:  ";                                //prompts user to enter start mileage for trip
        cin >> startmileage;                                                //user enters data

        cout << "enter ending mileage:  ";                                  //prompts user to enter end mileage for trip
        cin >> endmileage;                                                  //user enters data

        milesdriven = startmileage + endmileage;                            //calculates total miles driven

        totalmiles += milesdriven;

        cout << "Miles Driven:  " << milesdriven << endl;                   //outputs total miles driven to screen

        milespergallon = milesdriven / gallonsused;                         //calculates total miles per gallon

        cout << "Miles Per Gallon:  " << milespergallon << endl;            //outputs miles per gallon to screen
    } 

   // Show grand totals
    cout << "Grand totals:" << endl;

    cout << "Total Miles Driven: " << totalmiles << endl;
    cout << "Total Miles Per Gallon: " << totalmiles/totalgallons << endl;

    WrapUp();
```

Comment: I tried that and it ends regardless of whether it's -1 or a positive value. I'm trying to get it to enter all info and then go to a secondary, tertiary, etc. value until -1 is entered, which it then does the cumulative totals: Here is what I added...

Comment: It'd be a good idea to also exit the loop on input failure at that point

Comment: @Clarky7782 It should work if you copied what I wrote. Make sure you didn't type `=` instead of `==`, that's a common error.

Comment: @Clarky7782 Display the totals after the loop is done.

Comment: thank you so much! That compiled to where it exits when -1 is entered. Would I just put the running totals in where you put the break?

Comment: What do you mean "it compiled to where it exits"? Compiling is when you convert the code to an executable. Running the program is separate from that.

Comment: The running totals are fine. You can put the grand totals inside the `if`, or you could put it after the loop is done.

Comment: Put the grand totals where you have `WrapUp()`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say ran without errors (still learning the terminology). When I run what you gave me, it exits the screen. Where would I enter the cumulative totals to show after the sentinel value is entered and the loop ends?

Comment: sorry, just saw your follow up post

Comment: ok, I attempted to put it by the wrap up, but I think I'm missing something that would total up a grand total of what I've entered in with positive values:

Comment: }

 totalgallonsused = gallonsused;
 cout << "Total Gallons used:  " << totalgallonsused << endl;



WrapUp();  //indicates end of code

Comment: The grand total will be the same as the last running total. Are you sure you need to print it again?

Comment: thank you! This ran, but only gave a grand total of the last info I entered prior to -1, rather than a sum of all of the entries. I apologize if I'm not giving concise enough information.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to do a sum of total gallons used, miles driven, and overall average MPG

Comment: to where I have separate logs for each time I enter, which give the totals and averages (mentioned above) at the end.

Comment: I didn't read your code carefully. I thought you were adding each input to running totals, but you're not

Answer (score 0):

The body of the loop (between curly braces) is treated as a single unit, repeated by the do-while control. Try putting an if statement after you cin the gallons used to check for -1, use a break to exit the loop. Experimenting with that should help.

Answer (score 0):

`while` expressions, like the condition in a `for` loop, are evaluated at their position in the code, they are not supervisory.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   int i = 0;
   do {
       std::cout << i << " ";
       i += 2;
       std::cout << i << ' ';
       i -= 1;
       std::cout << i << ' ';
   } while (i != 2);
}
```

outputs:

```
0 2 1 1 3 2
```

live demo: http://ideone.com/7JWLp7